# Getting the address of a label in C

Tags: c, macros, linux-kernel

I found this macro in the linux kernel, while trying to figure out how to get the address of a label in C

```
#define _THIS_IP_  ({ __label__ __here; __here: (unsigned long)&&__here; })
```

And it is used like

```
(tsk)->task_state_change = _THIS_IP_;
```

We are implementing our own OS as part of Grad OS course and my purpose is to return to a label after calling `schedule()`. Linux Kernel somehow achieves this with the above macro.

Isn't it to be done like this?
( Please assume that I have the necessary assembly underneath to read and write registers. This is just pseudo code I want to show to emphasise how I plan to take the address of a label )

```
register_struct.rip = &&ret; /* GCC extension '&&' */
/* register_struct is a structure that holds all the registers of 
 * a process. Its useful to save and restore a process' state
 */
schedule();
ret: /* some code here */
```

I really don't understand how Linux Kernel code is achieving the same through `_THIS_IP_`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`register_struct` is probably a backup of the content of all the registers. It might point (i.e. contain pointers) to user address space, not kernel address space.

There is no way in standard C99 or GNU99 to assign a register without using `asm`. and the instruction pointer is not assignable on x86-64 (you need some jumping instruction).

Your `_THIS_IP_` macro (using several GCC extensions: [statement expressions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html) & [local labels](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Local-Labels.html) & [labels as values](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html)) is simply a way to get, as a `void*` pointer, the address of (or near to) the current instruction. This address could be later jumped to, e.g. with an indirect jump (`goto *addr;`)

Comment: I am not assigning RIP directly. I indeed use something like `iretq`. This is just pseudo code that I put up to show my method of taking the address of a label. Sorry for the uncler Qn!